# How can i compare two list of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
list1:


[
    {'id': 1, 'location': 'Mumbai', 'job_description': 'python'},
    {'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}
]


list2:

[
    {'preferred_location': 'Bengaluru', 'skills': 'python'},
    {'preferred_location': 'Hyderabad', 'skills': 'java'},
    {'preferred_location': 'Cochin', 'skills': 'angular'}
]
```

How can i compare first list with second list as per location.
from first list of location should match with second list prefered location.

And the expected resule will be

```
        [
            {'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}
        ]
```

Because "location" of first list matches with "preferred_location" of second list2
and will display foo that only

Comment: Can you describe to a human being what to do exactly? You'd only have to translate that to Python then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's employ list comprehensions to solve this problem.

```
list1 =[{'id': 1, 'location': 'Mumbai', 'job_description': 'python'},
    {'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}]


list2=[{'preferred_location': 'Bengaluru', 'skills': 'python'},
    {'preferred_location': 'Hyderabad', 'skills': 'java'},
    {'preferred_location': 'Cochin', 'skills': 'angular'}]

list2_locations= [i['preferred_location'] for i in list2]

list2_locations
     ['Bengaluru', 'Hyderabad', 'Cochin']

list1_final = [i for i in list1 if i['location'] in list2_locations]

list1_final
     [{'id': 2, 'job_description': 'software engineer', 'location': 'Bengaluru'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, keeping the dictionaries in `list1` where the locations match:

```
r1 = range(len(list1))
r2 = range(len(list2))
[list1[j] for i in r2 for j in r1 if list1[j]['location'] ==
                                     list2[i]['preferred_location']]


[{'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use use pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
[
{'id': 1, 'location': 'Mumbai', 'job_description': 'python'},
{'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}
]).set_index('location').reset_index()


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
[
{'preferred_location': 'Bengaluru', 'skills': 'python'},
{'preferred_location': 'Hyderabad', 'skills': 'java'},
{'preferred_location': 'Cochin', 'skills': 'angular'}
]).set_index('preferred_location').reset_index()


df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='inner', left_on='preferred_location', right_on='location')

del df3['location']

df3.to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [{'id': 1, 'location': 'Mumbai', 'job_description': 'python'}, 
{'id': 2, 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'job_description': 'software engineer'}
]
list2 = [{'preferred_location': 'Bengaluru', 'skills': 'python'}, 
{'preferred_location': 'Hyderabad', 'skills': 'java'}, 
{'preferred_location': 'Cochin', 'skills': 'angular'}
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='location', right_on='preferred_location', how='inner')


list_final = list(df3.T.to_dict().values())

print(list_final)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 2, 'job_description': 'software engineer', 'location': 'Bengaluru', 'preferred_location': 'Bengaluru', 'skills': 'python'}]
```